# How to put the XR21V1410 USB-UART bridge in 9N1 mode?

Tags: uart, windows

The [XR21V1410](https://www.maxlinear.com/product/interface/uarts/usb-uarts/xr21v1410) bridge can work with 9N1 UART symbols. To use such symbol format the XR21V1410 should be put in wide mode. [There](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/590d5d4a-7ff2-4792-bbd6-c393bfd98ffd/how-to-get-handle-of-serialport?forum=Vsexpressvb) is an amateur example on Basic which use some magic numbers:

```
Private Const ExarPortIndex = &H805
<...>
Dim ExarWriteCode As Long = CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, _
                                     ExarPortIndex + 17, _
                                     METHOD_BUFFERED, _
                                     FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
<...>
Private Sub WriteReg(ByVal Reg As UInt16, ByVal Data As UInt16)
    <...>
    Dim Status As Boolean = DeviceIoControl(PortHandle, ExarWriteCode, inPtr, 4, -1, 0, ReturnedBytes, 0)
    <...>
End Sub
<...>
WriteReg(&HD02, 1)                  ' Set Wide mode for XR21B1411
```

I have try to rewrite this example in C++. But the code does't not work. And the XR21V1410 does't enter to wide mode. Then I try to reduce my code and try to use the *DeviceIoControl* function to change baud rate:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winioctl.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hUart;
    CHAR uartName[] = "\\\\.\\COM8";
    hUart = CreateFileA(uartName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    DCB uartDCB;
    uartDCB.BaudRate    = CBR_9600;
    uartDCB.ByteSize    = 9;
    uartDCB.Parity      = NOPARITY;
    uartDCB.StopBits    = ONESTOPBIT;
    SetCommState(hUart, &uartDCB);

    DWORD bytesRet = 0;
    DWORD baudRate = CBR_14400;
    const UINT64 IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_BAUD_RATE = CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_SERIAL_PORT, 1, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS);
    DeviceIoControl(hUart, IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_BAUD_RATE, &baudRate, sizeof(baudRate), NULL, 0, &bytesRet, (LPOVERLAPPED)NULL);

    const UINT16 arrayLen = 2;
    UINT8 array[arrayLen];
    array[0] = 0x33;
    array[1] = 0xFF;
    WriteFile(hUart, array, arrayLen, &bytesReturned, NULL);
    
    CloseHandle(hUart);
    return 0;
}
```

It's work (I see it on my oscilloscope an in Serial Port Monitor log). But in the amateur example a CTL code use the FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN as device type (instead of FILE_DEVICE_SERIAL_PORT device type in my reduced code). Also I don't understand what *function* shall I set in the CTL_CODE macro...

```
#define CTL_CODE(DeviceType, Function, Method, Access) (  ((DeviceType) << 16) | ((Access) << 14) | ((Function) << 2) | (Method))
```

...and what data shall I put in the *DeviceIoControl* function as a lpInBuffer to set wide mode.

In the [XR21V1410 datasheet](https://assets.maxlinear.com/web/documents/xr21v1410.pdf#page=12) there is a USB control commands table:
[image]

Can someone give me an advise how shall can I change my code to put the XR21V1410 into wide mode?

**Addition**

I have enter to the wide mode with the next string:

```
DeviceIoControl(hUart, 0x22205C, (LPVOID)NULL, 0, (LPVOID)NULL, 0 ,&bytesReturned, (LPOVERLAPPED)NULL);
```

But the using of magic numbers is not a good practice. So I want to know how the 0x22205C number follows from the datasheet.

Comment: Can you try this mode with a terminal first? For example TeraTerm, Putty or picocom? The chip looks like a standard CDC so programming it should not be different than any other serial port, depending on your OS. pyserial is easy to start with.

Comment: "Can you try this mode with a terminal first?" For what? With my current code I actually get oscillograms 9N1 from Tx. But the 9th bit is always zero. Which corresponds to what is written in the datasheet. To get an ability to change the 9th bit I must (as it written in datasheet) put the XR21V1410 to the wide mode. How can Teraterm or Putty help here even if they could formally support 9-bits symbols?

Comment: I try PyTTY. Formally, it allows to set 9 bit length of symbols. But the 9th symbol is always zero. As in my code.

Comment: _"Bit-0 of the second byte that is loaded into the TX FIFO is bit-8 of the 9-bit data."_ You're loading the TX FIFO with `array[1] = 0xFF;`. Have you tried `0x01` instead of `0xFF`?

Comment: @Velvel The sending of 9-bit symbols now works. Yes I do. Actually I send 0x33,0x00 and 0x33,0xFF and the 9-th bit is changing. But the enter to the wide mode now based on a magic number 0x22205C. I want to know how this number follows from the datasheet.

Comment: @Velvel What do you mean "checked the CTL_CODE macro"?

Comment: The CTL_CODE macro is used to assemble the command: _const UINT64 IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_BAUD_RATE = `CTL_CODE`(FILE_DEVICE_SERIAL_PORT, 1, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)_. If you understand what this macro does, you can reverse the process and figure out what `0x22205C` means.

Comment: @Velvel "If you understand what this macro does, you can reverse". Ok, the 0x22 DeviceType is the FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, the 0x00 Access is the FILE_ANY_ACCESS. So the 0x22205С=CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x817, 0, FILE_ANY_ACCESS). The 0x817 is also the magic number.

Comment: From the info I've got, it doesn't make sense to me. The `WIDE_EN` flag is bit-0 of the `CUSTOM` register (address `0x03`). And the UART Custom registers have a block number of `0x66`.